# Angularstrap datapicker multi select

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap, datapicker

i have searched deep into web, but found nothing, do you know if there is a way to select multiple days using angularstrap datapicker?

There is always something similiar to Bootstrap UI:
https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.datepickerMultiSelect

But nothing for angularstrap, any advice?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using  MultipleDatePicker

here the github page:
https://github.com/arca-computing/MultipleDatePicker

example website :
http://arca-computing.github.io/MultipleDatePicker/

Comment: yep, already see it, but it don't extend angular-strap directive